# Filtering objects in jq by existence of nested array values

Tags: jq

Given a document like this:

```
[
  {
    "KVs" : [
      {
        "Key": "animal",
        "Value": "lion"
      },
      {
        "Key": "mascot",
        "Value": "lion"
      }
    ],
    "name": "roger"
  },
  {
    "KVs" : [
      {
        "Key": "animal",
        "Value": "zebra"
      },
      {
        "Key": "mascot",
        "Value": "lion"
      }
    ],
    "name": "linda"
  }
]
```

I want to use `jq` to select only those elements of the top array that contain the KV pair `animal == "lion"`.

The output for the above JSON document should be:

```
{
  "KVs" : [
    {
      "Key": "animal",
      "Value": "lion"
    },
    {
      "Key": "mascot",
      "Value": "lion"
    }
  ],
  "name": "roger"
}
```

Can't figure out how to accomplish this with `select()`. I know how to use it to select based on one specific field. e.g. by key name: `.[] | select(.KVs[].Key == "animal")`, right? But how do I tell it to match the same KV object on two fields (Key & Value)?

Answer (score 14):

NM, solved it with the help of jqplay and some trial and error.

This is the solution:
`.[] | select(.KVs[] | .Key == "animal" and .Value == "lion")`

([jqplay permalink](https://jqplay.org/s/JqcLjeSkgJ))

Comment: It doesn't matter here, since only one inner object matches, but in general you might prefer to use `any`. Compare `.[]|select(.KVs|any(.Value=="lion"))` and `.[]|select(.KVs[]|.Value=="lion")`

Comment: Interesting. But what is the difference, actually? Why would I prefer to use `any`?

Comment: Compare the number of results in both cases.

Comment: Note to return the value of the `name` element from the result (ie "roger"), use `.[] | select(.KVs[] | .Key == "animal" and .Value == "lion") | .name`